# Prepared statement in parameters?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Code:

```
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        String sql = "UPDATE Person SET address = ? WHERE name = ? ";
        pstmt=thecon.prepareStatement(sql);
        String addVar= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the new address");
        String nameVar=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Name");
        pstmt.setString(1 , addVar);
        pstmt.setString(2, nameVar);


        // Tell affected no of rows in table
        int num = pstmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      //Step 7: Process the results of the query
        System.out.println(num + " records updated"); 
        thecon.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("sql problem:   "+e);
    }
```

Exception:

> sql problem:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE name = ?' at line 1

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: what is problem with sql syntax?

Comment: You're using the wrong `executeUpdate` method, you should take the one without a string parameter.

Comment: as:                                                              int num = pstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Person SET address = ? WHERE name = ? ");

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:
String sql = "UPDATE Person SET address = ? WHERE name = ?;";

Comment: i try but still same error(You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE name = ?' at line 1)

Comment: sql query is all fine and there my sql syntax is case insensative so I don't see any problem. Can you try finding select address, name from person and see what you get?

Comment: semi-colons are not needed (and even discouraged) as you don't need a statement separator in JDBC (as - by specification - you only execute a single statement).

Comment: Now i try select statement as                                ("SELECT name,address phoneNum FROM person WHERE idperson= ? ";) but again another exception:(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jdbcEx.main)